# MVC\MVP frameworks for WinForms

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller, mvp

Are there any MVC\MVP alived frameworks for WinForms?

As I understand MVC# is dead.

http://www.mvcsharp.org/

Comment: Are you stuck using WinForms for a new application?

Comment: It's a fallacy that WinForms is obsolete.

Comment: I wouldn't put much stock in an MVC framework specifically for WinForms. That kind of misses the point of MVC: decoupling the view from the model.

Comment: 1. WPF is very resource consuming. 2. WinForms programming is simpler that WPF-programming. 3. To build WPF framework was a good idea, but implementation is disgusting. 4. Where is MVVM out of the box for WPF? There is no such. But, surprise, ASP.NET provides and forces MVC out of the box.

Comment: 5. True WPF programming requires enormous amount of WPF-specific knowledge incomparable with WinForms. 6. There are many apps don't need all those "beautiful" controls. 7. If you want to come up with beautiful design using WPF you still need to hire good designer.

Comment: 1. I have been programming on WPF last two years and still I recon that WinForms is far from death. 2. Our team developed almost a real time system, a ticket printing machine which should be able to work round the clock. There are several target hardware configs where our program should run. One of these configs looks like Celeron 1.8 Ghz with a 512Mb RAM with a very old graphics card. Now, do you want me to tell you the story of how "efficient" WPF under such a platform? On the contrary, similar Delphi program is very fast on such a platform.

Comment: And nobody wants to throw away this rusty hardware. This is a business. Nothing more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28560/discussion-between-highcore-and-engineer-spock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [WinForms MVP](http://winformsmvp.codeplex.com)?

From the CodePlex page:

> Based on the excellent Web Forms MVP, WinForms MVP is a simple Model
>   View Presenter framework for the Winforms platform.

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522809/WinForms-MVP-An-MVP-Framework-for-Winforms) provides an introduction to using the framework.